# Open component in new URL (React)

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have component with a button. I'd like a component to open another component in the new URL when the button is pressed. I don't want other components on the new page. I also want to pass data to a new component.

**UPDATE:**

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Link onClick={this.getData.bind(this)}  to={{ pathname: "/test", data: this.state.data }}>Begin</Link>
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/test" component={Test} />
    </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

I wrote some code, but I have 2 problems:

- How can I fetch data before route?
- My component "Test" render on this page with previous components, I want only "Test" component on page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see [react-router-dom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-dom) for page to page navigation and passing data from one page to another.

You can use switch from react router dom along with routes. Please see [documentation](https://reactrouter.com/) you will get to know about it.

Comment: Thanks, I wrote some code, but I still have problems. See above